# How should I size the transistors in the class AB linear amplifier

Tags: analog, linear-regulator, class-ab

If I want to design a class AB linear amplifier as the following one, how should I determine the width of the pmos and nmos?

[image]

Class AB amplifier specifications:

Vdd: 6V

Input: 0.5V to 5.5V

Output voltage 0.5V to 5.5V

Output current: -450mA to 450mA

Length: 180nm

As both pmos and nmos are either turned on or off, so they are in the triode region instead of in the saturation region, so I suppose the square-law formula as stated below is not applicable in this case. Am I correct?

[image]

So if the square-law formula cannot be used, what formula can be used for sizing the transistors in the linear amplifier? Thanks.

Comment: *Am I correct?* No, if the current into the load is zero, the voltage at OUT will be \$V_{DD}/2\$. Then both MOSFETs need to conduct a little bit to make \$I_Q\$ flow so their \$V_{GS}\$ will not be very large (if not, \$I_Q\$ would be large). That means \$V_{DS} > V_{DS,sat}\$ and the MOSFETs will be in saturation mode.

Comment: I agree with the points Tony makes in his answer. The main problem with your circuit proposal is that it will be **IMPOSSIBLE** to properly control the voltage at OUT without using **feedback**. The "driver stage" cannot generate the proper voltages for the MOSFETs without feedback. 99 out of 100 class AB amplifiers using MOSFETs use the MOSFETs in **common drain configuration**. Not common source like yours. There are good reasons why that is so.

Comment: If you're turning the FETs on or off, this is not a linear amplifier. So you'll have to be clearer what you're asking.

Comment: @BrianDrummond My wording may not be correct. But both nmos and pmos conduct for only half of the cycle. When they are not conducting, should I say that they are off? If not, at what stage are they? Thanks.

Comment: When they are not conducting they are off. When they are conducting in a linear amplifier they are not fully on, but have significant Vds, and Rds varying with Vgs.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie May I know why you say most of the class AB amplifiers use common-drain configuration instead of common-source? Also if a feedback is needed, does it mean that the "driver stage" has to have differential inputs? That is, one input for input voltage, another input for feedback. Thanks.

Comment: *But both nmos and pmos conduct for only half of the cycle* You're writing that as if that is **easy** and will happen **automatically**, **it will not**. It would require a very complex circuit in your "driver stage" block. If you use the MOSFETs in common-drain configuration, **it becomes much easier** and then *But both nmos and pmos conduct for only half of the cycle* is possible. I suggest that you **STUDY** some push-pull amplifier circuits and learn how they work.

Comment: *May I know why ...class AB amplifiers use common-drain configuration* Simply said: because the design becomes **much easier** and performance is **better**. It can be done with common source but there are a lot of pitfalls with doing that. **It is really not something a beginner should try to do**. Sorry but it is too complex to explain here, when you gain design experience, it will become obvious.

Comment: *Also if a feedback is needed, does it mean that the "driver stage" has to have differential inputs?* Yes, then basically the amplifier is like an **opamp**. I suggest that you study some basic **audio power amplifier circuits** (using MOSFETS or BJTs, it does not matter) and see how these are basically opamps with a feedback circuit.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters for FETs depend on your **design specs** for **RdsOn (<1% of load), Vds, load, Pmax, thermal margin, etc.**

Cross-conduction failure MUST BE avoided. (both Nch & Pch on at the same time)

With common-emitter, (CE) complementary drivers only one driver is active at a time. With voltage feedback, this eliminates the Vgs exponential factors and
eliminates the crossover-distortion with the Op Amp gain as error correction.

Each component in Class AB ought to be rated for power and temperature equal to the load so that at half power, you are derating your device dissipation and heat rise 50% which is prudent for any thermal design.

### update

On second thought, it is possible to use PAIRED DRAINS with current feedback. But phase shift with high gain and stray reactive loads will need phase margin compensation.  (not shown)

- [Here is my design](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgLCBsB0BMCsBTAtAdhARgAxy12qqAzFgByyQCcl6YRmW4sAUAC4gGyaVdGyMYeIASGQZY0QqjJFZ8VLFKV4GUTikzZkBamUZIDLGw4KOpUiD6NFFxmJCVoWIpBeUwlDHVIuDyHPDwkLBg-ApgqPCk8FzYRgDuJlwh1qY2wsyJYPqW-OA5RDEZAE651mRlHGCMAnhGpVZJlSnChkYASg4GsCHgFj0QIvB4wk7wrTXQ8Jn5BuIW2XOQNcydjfNmFhs14AJcOwGrlYXJ5pZFO9Wi4hOj01mQEJQGYI9VK6VBqVxf760YzAA5iBfpwQctLFhBhkAPIg1DdK6PaxXFYAM2OUNmkIgfEwUw4Rgx6wR2IwpNk+PG-GYDTy5IM60U-zq9UxuLyJxZdRmi0wzKZtl5BSKjS5CTJQj5LQl0qu0rObNeTzmYBV3NZM0aLRc-VRQMskD1jF1HCCExmXnVVo4vVlORayr+bJtAy6tuhcTwzAAhpg1X83S0tuMxOMvXVRqyyAgMKRiKg1fGCBh6LVNcCMDcEHNs4qMtV6OsXmALKQdvoAPqPStYSvieCvSsSMJQ8tYdyKSKoWtOPAYWvN+uQStEZiFywuQ0LN50faYHs1usNpstrDSUt4TvxqIjnB1Ad12D1ntj0pglpB1G2nmlV3mrPJc3p72JMGCZJpfWJUHyt4ymZ5ERRhfxWCcVFiZlkW4edU2rMBBzoRt62Pfc6hoSAggQet63HZxrjmZlHxg1oRyXStqkoUhew7IhIho7Cj2rUdmAAD35CBIgXAxUAWKoQFYuI2LNWJtA4SgBGkcB+MEowgA)
  [image]

I chose very low RdsOn (mOhm) power FETs with an ideal Op Amp to drive an inverting BJT to the FET with negative feedback to correct for all non-linearity.  I arbitrarily chose a voltage gain of 100 max.

Comment: You can design class AB with paired collectors (or drains, or anodes). The use of emitter follower final stages is not what makes a Class AB. The design may be more difficult but it's not impossible.

Comment: @BrianDrummond In fact, I see some Class AB amplifiers are in common-source topology. Others are in source-follower topology. In my understanding, common-source topology is chosen over source-follower topology because common-source topology can achieve a wider range of output voltage. Except that, what are other criteria to consider when choosing between common-source topology ad source-follower topology? Thanks.

Comment: @BrianDrummond paired collectors would demand current feedback to control Iq

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Yes they would (in a complementary transformerless AB amplifier) I agree : more difficult.

Comment: @TonySteward May I know why you said high gain feedback eliminates crossover distortion and why a charge pump DCDC? Also what do you mean by charge pump DCDC? Do you mean a current-mode DC-DC converter? Thanks.

Comment: No I mean a CMOS Charge Pump to raise the Gate voltage above Vdd  ...voltage error is reduced by Afb